# how to get color from colors.xml and set it in strings.xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have a string in `strings.xml` file. I want to set the color for the specific part of the String. Here's the Code.

```
<string name="welcome_name">Welcome to <font color='#00adb5'>Home</font> </string>
```

It works great. But I don't want to set color directly in String. I want to set it via `colors.xml` file

Like this below:

```
<string name="welcome_name">Welcome to <font color='@color/special_text_color'>Home</font> </string>
```

It doesn't working. How to make it work. Please Help me with some Solutions.

Answer (score 1):

In pure XML this will never work. It depends on how you use that XML.
So which software to you expect to understand '@color/special_text_color'?
Which software do you use to render that XML to a user?

Answer (score 1):

instead of set color in string.xml, you can use Spannble attribute to color specific text in string

```
TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview01);
Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("I know just how to whisper, And I know just how to cry,I know just where to find the answers");

wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 15, 30, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TV.setText(wordtoSpan);
```